# Aurelia StageComponent - how to render a child component into the DOM tree?

Tags: typescript, aurelia

If I have an app.html template as follows:

```
<template>
  <require from="./MyComponent"></require>
  <h1>${message}</h1>
  <my-component>test</my-component>
</template>
```

With MyComponent.ts :

```
export class MyComponent {
    myName : string;
}
```

And MyComponent.html:

```
<template>
    MyComponent
</template>
```

The following unit test will always fail:

```
import {App} from '../../src/app';
import {StageComponent} from 'aurelia-testing';
import {bootstrap} from 'aurelia-bootstrapper';

describe('the app', () => {
  var app ;
  beforeEach(() => {
    app = StageComponent
    .withResources('app')
    .inView('  <require from="./MyComponent"></require>' +
      '<h1>${message}</h1>' +
      '<my-component>test</my-component>')
    .boundTo(new App());
  } );

  it('says hello', (done) => {
    app.create(bootstrap).then( () => {
      var myComponent = document.querySelector('my-component');
      expect(myComponent.innerHTML).toContain('MyComponent');
      done();
    });

  });
});
```

Note that StageComponent correctly substitutes the ${message} within the template for app.html, but does not create a new MyComponent instance.
When running this within the browser, the DOM generated is:

```
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <my-component class="au-target" au-target-id="2">
    MyComponent
</my-component>
```

But when running the same code through StageComponent in a test, the DOM generated is:

```
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
<my-component>test</my-component>
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but I think you need to do this (or is adding customElement optional?)

```
import {customElement, bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';

@customElement('my-component')
export class MyComponent {
    @bindable myName : string;
}
```

then

```
it("test case", done => 
     StageComponent 
        .withResources("./full/path/to/MyComponent")
        .inView("<my-component></my-component>"))
        .create(bootstrap)
        .then(() => {...})
        .then(done);
```

It's not that clear to me why you are adding the same html that is inside the app.html, is that to demonstrate that it works, but not for a component?

Or what is it that you want to test?

- Do you want to test if the app view renders correctly with it's components?
- Or if the custom MyComponent render correctly?

Comment: Hi Eric,  thanks for the response.  What you are describing above is a test for the MyComponent element in isolation.  I am attempting to render the app component, and the MyComponent at the same time, which is the behaviour of the above code in the browser.  So to answer your questions, yes I want to test that the app view renders correctly with it's components.